# cannot feed value for tensor layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am running following code. I do understand we can use Keras. I am trying to learn tensorflow and using it develop simple 2 layer NN.

**Error: ValueError:** Cannot feed value of shape (100, 1024) for Tensor 'layer-1/dropout/mul_1:0', which has shape '(?, 50)'

```
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(456)
    import  tensorflow as tf
    tf.set_random_seed(456)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import deepchem as dc
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    def eval_tox21_hyperparams(n_hidden=50, n_layers=2, learning_rate=.001,
                               dropout_prob=0.5, n_epochs=45, batch_size=100,
                               weight_positives=True):

      print("---------------------------------------------")
      print("Model hyperparameters")
      print("n_hidden = %d" % n_hidden)
      print("n_layers = %d" % n_layers)
      print("learning_rate = %f" % learning_rate)
      print("n_epochs = %d" % n_epochs)
      print("batch_size = %d" % batch_size)
      print("weight_positives = %s" % str(weight_positives))
      print("dropout_prob = %f" % dropout_prob)
      print("---------------------------------------------")

      d = 1024
      graph = tf.Graph()
      with graph.as_default():
        _, (train, valid, test), _ = dc.molnet.load_tox21()
        train_X, train_y, train_w = train.X, train.y, train.w
        valid_X, valid_y, valid_w = valid.X, valid.y, valid.w
        test_X, test_y, test_w = test.X, test.y, test.w

        # Remove extra tasks
        train_y = train_y[:, 0]
        valid_y = valid_y[:, 0]
        test_y = test_y[:, 0]
        train_w = train_w[:, 0]
        valid_w = valid_w[:, 0]
        test_w = test_w[:, 0]

        # Generate tensorflow graph
        with tf.name_scope("placeholders"):
          x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, d))
          y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,))
          w = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,))
          keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        for layer in range(n_layers):
          print("present layer is ", layer)
          with tf.name_scope("layer-%d" % layer):
            W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, n_hidden)))
            b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, n_hidden)))
            print("x_hidden shape {} and W shape {}".format(x.shape, W.shape))
            x_hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
            # Apply dropout
            x_hidden = tf.nn.dropout(x_hidden, keep_prob)
            x = x_hidden
            d = n_hidden
        with tf.name_scope("output"):
          W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_hidden, 1)))
          b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1,1)))
          print("output W shape {} and x_hidden shape {} ".format(W.shape, x_hidden.shape))
          y_logit = tf.matmul(x_hidden, W) + b
          # the sigmoid gives the class probability of 1
          y_one_prob = tf.sigmoid(y_logit)
          # Rounding P(y=1) will give the correct prediction.
          y_pred = tf.round(y_one_prob)
          print("y pred shape {}".format(y_pred.shape))
        with tf.name_scope("loss"):
          # Compute the cross-entropy term for each datapoint
          y_expand = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
          print("y expand shape {} ".format(y_expand.shape))
          entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_logit, labels=y_expand)
          print("entropy  shape {} ".format(entropy.shape))
          # Multiply by weights
          if weight_positives:
            w_expand = tf.expand_dims(w, 1)
            entropy = w_expand * entropy
            print("entropy weight postives  shape {} ".format(entropy.shape))
          # Sum all contributions
          l = tf.reduce_sum(entropy)

        with tf.name_scope("optim"):
          train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(l)

        with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
          tf.summary.scalar("loss", l)
          merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

        #hyperparam_str = "d-%d-hidden-%d-lr-%f-n_epochs-%d-batch_size-%d-weight_pos-%s" % (
        #    d, n_hidden, learning_rate, n_epochs, batch_size, str(weight_positives))
        #train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/fcnet-func-' + hyperparam_str,
        #                                     tf.get_default_graph())
        N = train_X.shape[0]
        with tf.Session() as sess:
          sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
          step = 0
          for epoch in range(n_epochs):
            pos = 0
            while pos < N:
              batch_X = train_X[pos:pos+batch_size]
              batch_y = train_y[pos:pos+batch_size]
              batch_w = train_w[pos:pos+batch_size]
              feed_dict = {x: batch_X, y: batch_y, w: batch_w, keep_prob: dropout_prob}
              _, summary, loss = sess.run([train_op, merged, l], feed_dict=feed_dict)
              #print("epoch %d, step %d, loss: %f" % (epoch, step, loss))
              train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)

              step += 1
              pos += batch_size

          # Make Predictions (set keep_prob to 1.0 for predictions)
          valid_y_pred = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={x: valid_X, keep_prob: 1.0})

        weighted_score = accuracy_score(valid_y, valid_y_pred, sample_weight=valid_w)
        print("Valid Weighted Classification Accuracy: %f" % weighted_score)
      return weighted_score

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      score = eval_tox21_hyperparams()
```

Comment: What is the error or difficulty you are facing?

Comment: error is shown in description. Thanks